# What does hierarchy = hierarchy[0] mean in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I've been tasked to translate some Python code into C#, and I've been having some difficulty as I have no experience with Python, and the program is even using OpenCV and NumPy.

This is the part of the code, and I'm not sure how `hierarchy[0]` is being assigned

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
```

Comment: It looks like sloppy reuse of an identifier to mean different things at different times in the same scope. A new variable would have been more readable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah I see now. Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about that assignment.

Just from reading the code, it is clear to me that the `findContours()` method returns a tuple of three values, the third one is a sequence and is assigned to `hierarchy`. The next line then just takes the first element from that sequence and assigns it back to the same name.

If you are trying to understand *why* it does this and how to translate this to C++, you'd need to go [read the `cv2::findContours()` documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a). When looking at `cv2` documentation, it's always going to show you the C++ version, and C++ uses *output arguments*; `findCountours()` takes `contours` and `hierarchy` as two output arrays, to which the function will write.

In Python code, you just get the arrays as return values instead. Here, `hierarchy` is documented as

> Optional output vector, containing information about the image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours.

So `hierarchy[0]` has information on the first contour found, and any other elemens are discarded.

In a C++ translation of the code, you'd have to pass in arrays for both `contours` and `hierarchy`, then again extract the first element from the latter.